# Method Overload Error

Tags: java, methods, overloading, velocity

my velocity method keeps giving me an error saying

"No applicable overload for the method named 'velocity' was found in type "Velocity". Perhaps you wanted the overload version 'void velocity (double distance, double time) throws java.io.IOException;' instead?"

I'm not really sure how I can fix this, but if you guys can help, that would be great, thanks.

Anyways, here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Velocity
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    velocity ();
}


public static void velocity (double distance, double time) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    System.out.println ("Please input distance in meters:");
    distance = Double.parseDouble (myInput.readLine ());
    System.out.println ("Please input time in seconds:");
    time = Double.parseDouble (myInput.readLine ());
    System.out.println ("Therefore your velocity is " + distance / time + " m/s.");
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think `velocity ();` should do and why?

Comment: No offence but it would be wise to read up on how methods work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a method velocity (); instead you should call

```
velocity (1d, 2d);
```

This is the reason for error.

Regarding overloading:

if you have another method with same name like:

```
public static void velocity() throws IOException () {
   //body
}
```

Then you are overloading the method velocity here. So define it and it should work.

Comment: I just have one question though, I tried looking up what 1d and 2d mean but I couldn't find it. What do they do exactly?

Comment: You are passing in two parameters of double (d after number means double) type.

Answer (score 0):

The only method velocity the compiler can find is:

```
public static void velocity (double distance, double time) throws IOException
```

Your call in main is to a method velocity without any parameters. There's no such method. The compiler is finding the static method with the same name, and basically saying 'this is as close as I find to what you're calling, is that what you mean?'.

Assuming you are trying to invoke the static method, you need pass arguements for distance and time.